# Passing a struct to a function in a header file

Tags: c++, class, struct

When I put the function print in the pointerStruct.cpp with everything else it works fine but when I try to separate the function into a header file I am no longer able to figure out the problem. Any ideas would be great.

pointerStruct.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include "pointerStru.h"

using namespace std;

struct student
{
       char name[20];
       int num;
       float score[3];
};

int main()
{
       struct student stu;
       PointerStru pstttt;

       stu.num=12345;
       strcpy(stu.name,"li li");
       stu.score[0]=67.5;
       stu.score[1]=89;
       stu.score[2]=78.6;

       pstttt.print(&stu);
}
//pointerStru.h
#ifndef PointerStru_H_INCLUDED
#define PointerStru_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PointerStru{

    private:

    public:
        void print(struct student *p)
        {
            cout << "*p " << p << endl;
            cout<<p->num<<"\n"<<p->name<<"\n"<<p->score[0]<<"\n"
                    <<p->score[1]<<"\n"<<p->score[2]<<"\n";
            cout<<" ";
        }

};


#endif // PointerStru_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?!

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Do you mean you put print() in the header file, or PointerStru?  You would need the entire class in the header file.

Comment: In member function 'void PointerStru::print(student*)'
pointerStru.h|15|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct student'
pointerStru.h|12|error: forward declaration of 'struct student'

Comment: Your `pointerStru` header needs to include `student.h`.

Comment: Also, in c++ you don't need to say "struct student" every time you use it. It's sufficient to say just "student". I.e. void print(student* p) is a correct declaration. (the only difference between a class and a struct in c++ is that a struct default visibility is public, a class defaults to private.)

Comment: print() is in the class PointerStru and the class PointerStru is in pointerStru.h

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `struct student` is not defined before it is used in the header. Either include it within the header, or forward declare it as an opaque struct and define the implementation of `PointerStru::print` in the .cpp file (after the definition of `struct student`).

On an unrelated note, `using namespace std;` in a header file is wrong and evil. Never do it.

Comment: also don't define methods in header file, because it defeats the purpose, just declare it in header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a definition of the print method in the header file, then a compiler knows only that the student is a struct (from print argument list, when it is declared as struct), but have no idea how this struct is defined (the definition is later in cpp file).
In this case the compiler treats it as a incomplete type and raise an error.

In case you define print method in cpp file below student structure definition the compiler will be able to compile the code (it knows how student structure is defined, before it is displayed in print method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
//pointerStru.h
#ifndef PointerStru_H_INCLUDED
#define PointerStru_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

struct student;

class PointerStru{

private:

public:
    void print(struct student *p);

};


#endif // PointerStru_H_INCLUDED

#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include "pointerStru.h"

using namespace std;

struct student
{
   char name[20];
   int num;
   float score[3];
};

void PointerStru::print(struct student *p)
{
   cout << "*p " << p << endl;
   cout<<p->num<<"\n"<<p->name<<"\n"<<p->score[0]<<"\n"
        <<p->score[1]<<"\n"<<p->score[2]<<"\n";
   cout<<" ";
}

int main()
{
   struct student stu;
   PointerStru pstttt;

   stu.num=12345;
   strcpy(stu.name,"li li");
   stu.score[0]=67.5;
   stu.score[1]=89;
   stu.score[2]=78.6;

   pstttt.print(&stu);
}
```